# Delete query sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete the session and exercises related to that session using:

```
$delete_session =

"DELETE FROM sessions, exercises 
USING sessions 
INNER JOIN exercises 
ON sessions.session_id = exercises.session_id 
WHERE sessions.session_id= '$delete_id'";
```

The above query works if there are exercises linked to the session but doesn't fire if the session has no exercises.

Can I use the above query and below one together?

```
"DELETE FROM sessions WHERE session_id= '$delete_id'";
```

How could I get it that the session will delete with or without exercises linked to it?

Comment: Try with `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use LEFT INNER JOIN

```
$delete_session =
"DELETE FROM sessions, exercises 
USING sessions 
LEFT INNER JOIN exercises 
ON sessions.session_id = exercises.session_id 
WHERE sessions.session_id= '$delete_id'";
```